# How do I search for a redirected email using EWS JAVA api?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am sending an email using EWS and before I send it, I obtain the Message-ID of the message and using this I can search the email in the recipient mailbox (A). This email further gets automatically redirected to another mailbox (B) based on a rule set in outlook and I want to search the email in the redirected mailbox (B). Now since the Message-ID is different, I cant search the email based on Message-Id. Is there any way out for this?

```
    Received: from ****************** (**********) by
 *********************** with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id

Received: from ****************([********************]) by
 ******************* ([*****************]) with mapi id *******************; Thu,
 3 May 2018 09:33:45 +1200
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: ************************
To: **************************
Subject: From: ******************************
Thread-Topic: From: ******************************
Thread-Index: ************************
Date: Thu, 3 May 2018 09:33:44 +1200
Message-ID: <******************@************
Accept-Language: en-US, en-NZ
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: ******************************>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: **********************
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-Originating-IP: [10.70.34.43]
Return-Path: *************************
```

Comment: There are one set of people on SO eager to help and there are another set of people eager to downvote the question or give out negative comments who cant help.

Question has enough research background to indicate that the Message-ID was obtained in the first request but the same cannot be carried forward, not sure what is not clear and definitely would help someone who comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839592.aspx (or the MIME References Message header) should contain the original MessageId, however if its been forward,replied multiple times this property won't just contain that MessageId but all the associated MessagesId's. I would suggest you look at a Message using and MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy which will let you see both the PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES and the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W properties and then you can build you search from there.

Comment: I used OutlookSpy to get the PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES property of the forwarded message but it is blank. I see there are a lot of properties associated with the message but I couldn't correlate the forwarded message with the original message. Is there any other property that can help?

Comment: If you can post the transport header and remove all the personnel information there maybe something there. It's strange because I see that prop populated in the same instance

Comment: I have edited the question with PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W

Comment: So is the message you looking for attached to the Message of the headers that your showing. That what it looks like to me, if its forwarding as an attachment your not going to be able to search by messageId even if its not an attachment based on the headers It doesn't look searchable. Normally in a reply or forward you would have a number of options like PR_Referances In-ReplyTo etc that you could use to trace but you header shows none of these. The only other thing i could think to try is look at the MIMEcontent of one of the Target Messages your trying to search on.

Comment: Its the main message that I am searching and the PR_References & In-ReplyTo both are blank since its a forwarded message and not a replied message.

Comment: Well you can only search based on what is there on a forwarded message the PR_Referances still should be filled in and is on the latest version of Exchange with Outlook forwarding rules (older versions may behave differently etc). But you can only search based on what is in the Messages if you can't find a Header or MAPI property to do the job then It may not work for you.

Comment: I think the only other way is to add an unique identifier (GUID) in the mail body or subject and track it. Thanks anyway for your help. I hope someone will find your answer useful.